# Convert date time to C# timetick in Dart (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

How can we convert current date time to timetick in flutter / dart? Already tried different formulas and calculation, didn't work. http://www.datetimetoticks-converter.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did it for the date.

You can copy the implementation made in C# in dart.

[DateTime.DateToTicks(...)](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,891f8af5025ab2f3)

```dart
void main() {
  final dateTime = DateTime.now();
  print(DateTimeUtils.dateToTicks(
    dateTime.year,
    dateTime.month,
    dateTime.day,
  ));
}
class DateTimeUtils {
  static const int TicksPerMillisecond = 10000;
  static const int TicksPerSecond = TicksPerMillisecond * 1000;
  static const int TicksPerMinute = TicksPerSecond * 60;
  static const int TicksPerHour = TicksPerMinute * 60;
  static const int TicksPerDay = TicksPerHour * 24;
  static List<int> daysToMonth365 = [
    0,
    31,
    59,
    90,
    120,
    151,
    181,
    212,
    243,
    273,
    304,
    334,
    365,
  ];
  static List<int> daysToMonth366 = [
    0,
    31,
    60,
    91,
    121,
    152,
    182,
    213,
    244,
    274,
    305,
    335,
    366,
  ];
  static int dateToTicks(int year, int month, int day) {
    if (year >= 1 && year <= 9999 && month >= 1 && month <= 12) {
      List<int> days = isLeapYear(year) ? daysToMonth366 : daysToMonth365;
      if (day >= 1 && day <= days[month] - days[month - 1]) {
        int y = year - 1;
        double n = y * 365 + y / 4 - y / 100 + y / 400 + days[month - 1] + day - 1;
        return n * TicksPerDay as int;
      }
    }
    throw new ArgumentError();
  }
  static bool isLeapYear(int year) {
    if (year < 1 || year > 9999) {
      throw new ArgumentError();
    }
    return year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks and what about date and time?

Comment: I think it's DateToTicks + TimeToTicks.
Look at the implementation in C#.